# Permissions required for changing Document Name

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

What permissions are required for a User to Update Document 'Name' in editform while uploading document in SharePoint document library.

It seems user has no issue while specifying any other property but get access denied if change document name?

Comment: You'll get a better response if you ask on [sharepoint.se]

Answer (score 2):

User needs the permission to delete. Yes, really. If you need renaming and want to prevent users from deleting documents, you'll need a custom ItemDeleting receiver.